# Next-word Generation in Tabular Dataset

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, text, text-generation

I'll build next-word generation using Tensorflow to predict address mapping. But, I saw many tutorial, next-word generation use long-text narration for its training dataset. But, I have dataset structure like this below (in dataframe). I'm confusing to slicing it into the predictors and label.
this data below assumed as a dataframe:

```
input                                        output/label
250 Hartford Avenue, Bellingham, MA, 2019    {'address': 'Hartford Avenue', 'city': 'Bellingham', 'state': 'MA','zip': '2019'}  
700 Oak Street, Brockton, MA, 2301           {'address': 'Oak Street', 'city': 'Brockton', 'state': 'MA', 'zip': '2301'}
```

if the dataset is narration, next-word generation usually has slicing data like this:

```
Hartford Aven u
artford Avenu e
```

But, if I have my own dataset that has to slicing the label from different column (the dataframe), how it must be?

Comment: I don't understand the question: what do you mean by "I'm confusing to slicing it into the x and y" and "it's if the dataset is narration", and " have my own dataset that has to slicing the label from different column" ?

Comment: I have edited the caption, hope it's better to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The model is currently predicting the next single character. The output of the model should be the next token.